# Send SIP traces over TCP from Kamailio to Heplify

Tags: sip, kamailio

I am using `siptrace` module to send traces to Heplify from Kamailio. By default traces are send using UDP, but we would like to send them over TCP.

Reading `siptrace` module [documentation](https://www.kamailio.org/docs/modules/devel/modules/siptrace.html) does not easily show how to use TCP instead.

How to configure `siptrace` module in Kamailio to use TCP when sending traces to Heplify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send via TCP have to add `;transport=tcp` to `duplicate_uri` setting.

> modparam("siptrace", "duplicate_uri", "sip:10.1.1.1:5888;transport=tcp")